# identify different points

Tags: r, statistical-significance, clustering, group-differences

I have a large scatterplot, with about 100,000 (x,y) points. The x coordinate is the set of numbers from (1 to ~100,000) - in other words, no 2 points have the same x-coordinate. The y is mostly constant (around 50-70 in value), but there are key "regions" where the y value spikes to ~120 or drops to ~20. How would I statistically differentiate these regions?

Clustering?
Any other ideas?

As a bonus, if you know R, if you could reference a certain method that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Have you considered first a simple correlation analysis?  There is a plethora of classification methods out there.  If you really want to differentiate regions I would start with goggling classification methods and seeing which ones seem to fit what you are looking for.

Comment: What do $x$ and $y$ represent?  Could this be a time series?

Comment: Yeah, so I am quite new at statistics. I am a high school sophomore and have only taken AP statistics (101 statistics in college, I think) so I have almost no real experience. What kind of correlation analysis? R-squared?

Comment: @whuber It is actually a genomic data problem. X is genomic location on a chromosome and Y is the number of mutations at that location.

Comment: @whuber Does that clarify the problem well enough?

Comment: Although it is unclear what you mean by "statistically differentiate," it sounds like material on [peak detection in signal processing](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36309) and [change-point methods](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change-point?sort=votes&pageSize=30) would potentially be relevant and useful.  Possibly some related material also appears in [threads referencing "genome"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=genome). Perhaps, after perusing some of these, you might be able to edit this question to clarify further what you need.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the purpose of "differentiating" these regions of higher or lower y-value?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest starting with a [kernel-smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_smoother) method.

This could be used to create essentially a moving average of *y* over each *x* that takes into account neighboring values of *y*, weighted by their distance away from the target *x*.

You could then set some threshold for identification for regions of *x*, based on the height and width of this moving average.  Something like the average kernel-smoothed value of *y* is above 75 for at least 5 consecutive units of *x*.